# What is the difference between Local System and Administrator Account?

Tags: c#, printing, windows-services, network-printers, windows-users

I have a `Print Service` when I change the Logon account to `Administrator`, The service worked well, but when I changed back to `Local System Account`, the service cannot find the Network printer and can not print. So I want to know what is the difference between `Local System Account` and `Administrator account`? How to configure my Print Service to access the network printer without logon as Administrator account?

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking to run the service under the `Network Service` account.

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work, do you know anyway to run window service as lauching user (current user logged to window)?

Comment: Services (generally) run when windows starts up, before any particular user has logged in. Multiple users can also log in. So no, there's no concept of running a service under a logged in users account.

Comment: Thank bro, but Network Service didn't work. May I missed something?